# Using Swift 4 Decodable to parse JSON with mixed property values

Tags: json, swift, swift4, decodable

I am trying to update my app to use Swift 4 Decodable - and am pulling down data from a JSON api which has child values which could be:

- A Child Object
- A String
- An Int

Here is the Json Api response:

```
var jsonoutput =
"""
{
"id": "124549",
"key": "TEST-32",
"fields": {
"lastViewed": "2018-02-17T21:40:38.864+0000",
"timeestimate": 26640
}
}
""".data(using: .utf8)
```

I have tried to parse it using the following: which works if I just reference the id and key properties which are both strings.

```
struct SupportDeskResponse: Decodable{
    var id: String
    var key: String
    //var fields: [String: Any] //this is commented out as this approach doesn't work - just generated a decodable protocol error.            
}

var myStruct: Any!
do {
    myStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode(SupportDeskResponse.self, from: jsonoutput!) 
} catch (let error) {
    print(error)
}

print(myStruct)
```

How do I decode the fields object into my Struct?

Answer (score 5):

You should create a new Struct adopting Decodable protocol like this :

```
struct FieldsResponse: Decodable {
    var lastViewed: String
    var timeestimate: Int
}
```

Then you can add it to your SupportDeskResponse

```
var fields: FieldsResponse
```